# MvcHttpHandler doesn't seem to implement IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to do a custom ActionResult for a MVC controller. In the example i'm looking at it shows the snippet bellow. My System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandle doesn't implement the IHttpHandler interface. The System.Web.Mvc.dll is version 1.0.0.0. Should i just write my own httphandler or is there something specific to the MvcHttpHandler that i need to use in a Controller ActionResult?

```
/// <summary>
/// Transfers execution to the supplied url.
/// </summary>
public class TransferResult : RedirectResult
{
    public TransferResult(string url)
        : base(url)
    {
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        httpContext.RewritePath(Url, false);

        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

~B

Comment: Did this code compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution

I changed:

```
IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
```

to:

```
IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHandler(context.RequestContext);
```